# Category WYSIWYG

Tags: categories, wysiwyg

I`m currently working with categories in ExpressionEngine and facing the problem that i missing some kind of WYSIWYG editor.

An search on Devot:ee gives me no result.

Is there an solution or an fieldtype that add an WYSIWYG editor to an category description field?

Cheers, Rein

Comment: I have never found one, but if you do I would love to know about it

Comment: Reinos, would you mind marking this as answered if my answer covers it for you?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If yes, please mark the answer correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: How about 'Wygwam' does this have any ability in this area?

Comment: Not that i know. The docs say nothing about this subject.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

DevDemon's Editor add-on does this. [Editor on devot:ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/editor).

[image]

Comment: Sweet, did not know about this.

Answer (score 1):

There are also some hacks to shoehorn wygwam (and possibly others) into the category description field.
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/219408/